# property subscribe does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having an constant error that tends to pop up in my code (using Visual Studio Code as my IDE):

> Property subscribe does not exist on type 'void'.....

When I run the code, I get an error message in Ionic localhost.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsService.getData('everything?q=bitcoin&from=2018-10-09&sortBy=publishedAt')
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: note: when i add the "return" doesnt work, still brings out the error

Comment: Please show this.newsService.getData(), guessing you are returning void on that function which is not what you want. you will need to use and Observable rather than void.

Comment: you are not returning anything into the `getData` function. It should be something like `return this.http.method(...params);` (method is .post .get. ecc)

Comment: i did add the "return" method but still the same 'void' error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method should return observable to have opportunity subscribe on it.

This is an example how to use Observable:

**models/post.ts**

```
export interface IPost {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

export class Post implements IPost {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    constructor(postData: any) {
        this.id = postData.id;
        this.title = postData.title;
    }
}
```

**posts.service.ts**

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>(url)
        .pipe(
            map(response => response.map(postData => new Post(postData)))
        );
}
```

### Usage. Option 1:

**posts.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
        this.posts = posts;
    });
}
```

**posts.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="posts">
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <span>{{post.title}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Usage. Option 2. Using an async pipe:

**posts.component.ts**

```
postsObservable: Observable<Post[]>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.postsObservable = this.postsService.getPosts();
}
```

**posts.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="postsObservable | async; let posts">
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <span>{{post.title}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: kindly explain how to implement "observable", because am just a beginner learning the angular and ionic coding world

Comment: @JamesMacharia Don't forget to unsubscribe. It's very important.